# how to insert a php variable in a sql query?

Tags: php, mysql

now i have two drop down lists, one is for name and the other is time. I want when the user clicks on the desired name in the first dropdown box, the time displayed in the second drop box should belong to the name choosed in the first dropdown box.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","fyp");
$query1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT fname FROM lecturer");

echo "Select lecturer:<select name= 'fname'>";
$name = 'fname';
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
{
   echo "<option value='". $row['fname']."'>".$row['fname']. '</option>';
}
   echo '</select>';

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","fyp");
$query3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT stime FROM studbooking WHERE lecname is '$name'");

echo "Select Booking time:<select name= 'stime'>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query3))
{
   echo "<option value='". $row['stime']."'>".$row['stime']. '</option>';
}
   echo '</select>';
```

how to use php variables in sql query?

Comment: Are you looking forward to use `eval()`?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `mysql_real_escape_string`. Bind the params or use the `mysqli` equivalent.

Comment: You can't mix mysql and mysqli functions. If you're going to escape the variable instead of using parametrized queries, you must use `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysqli->bind_param for this.

[mysqli::bind_param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Example

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT stime FROM studbooking WHERE lecname=?");
$statement->bind_param('s', $name);
$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: You may want to elaborate how the OP can use what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
```

to:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name);
```

You can't use `mysql` functions with a `mysqli` connection, and vice versa.